# PyTorch paste values into tensor by row index with increasing column index

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor `output` into which I want to put some `values`. I know the row that each value should go in, but I don't have an index tensor describing the columns. Instead, if there are `k` values that belong to one row, they should go in columns 0, 1, ..., k-1. This is perhaps better explained with an example:

```py
import torch

n = 4
max_cols = 5
output = torch.zeros(n, max_cols)
row_idx = torch.tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3])
values = torch.arange(len(row_idx)).float() # the values could be anything, not just arange
# output[??] = values
```

Here the first 4 values should be in output at [0, 0], ... [0, 3], the next 2 values at [1, 0], [1, 1], and so on.

Here's how I'm doing this now

```py
_, counts = torch.unique(row_idx, return_counts=True)
range_ = torch.arange(max_cols)
col_idx = torch.cat([range_[:c] for c in counts])
output[row_idx, col_idx] = values
output
```

```
tensor([[0., 1., 2., 3., 0.],
        [4., 5., 0., 0., 0.],
        [6., 7., 8., 0., 0.],
        [9., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Is there any more efficient way to paste these values into the appropriate positions?

(feel free to suggest a better title for this if you can think of one)

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution has linear time complexity. So, I am not sure if it can be further improved. However, I think the solution you provided is not correct. Let me give an example.

For the following input:

```
row_idx = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3])
```

Your solution outputs the following.

```
tensor([[4., 1., 3., 3., 0.],
        [2., 5., 2., 0., 0.],
        [6., 7., 8., 0., 0.],
        [9., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

However, I think your expected output is:

```
tensor([[0., 1., 3., 4., 0.],
        [2., 5., 0., 0., 0.],
        [6., 7., 8., 0., 0.],
        [9., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

So, I suggest the following solution that I believe is correct.

```
def helper(a):
    idx = a.cumsum(-1)
    id_arr = torch.ones(idx[-1], dtype=int)
    id_arr[0] = 0
    id_arr[idx[:-1]] = -a[:-1]+1
    return id_arr.cumsum(-1)

n = 4
max_cols = 5
output = torch.zeros(n, max_cols)
row_idx = torch.tensor([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3])
values = torch.arange(len(row_idx)).float()

count = torch.unique(row_idx, return_counts=True)[1]
col_idx = helper(count)[row_idx.argsort().argsort()]
output[row_idx, col_idx] = values
print(output)
```

---

**Update**

You can simply add one line to your code as follows to make it work correctly.

```
_, counts = torch.unique(row_idx, return_counts=True)
range_ = torch.arange(max_cols)
col_idx = torch.cat([range_[:c] for c in counts])
col_idx = col_idx[row_idx.argsort().argsort()] # <== UPDATE
output[row_idx, col_idx] = values
print(output)
```

Comment: Ah, yes, in my case the row indices are always sorted already. That's a good catch, though. If nobody posts anything simpler / faster in a bit, I'll accept this for being more general. Do you use `helper` instead of just sorting the row indices to avoid being O(n log n)? (I don't know if PyTorch has a radix sort)

Comment: No, the helper function is just a substitute for the first three lines that you have in your code. `_, counts = torch.unique(row_idx, return_counts=True);
range_ = torch.arange(max_cols);
col_idx = torch.cat([range_[:c] for c in counts]);` In your code, if you add the line: `col_idx = col_idx [row_idx.argsort().argsort()]`, I think that would work for you too.